# php filtering json file and returning an attribute value

Tags: php, json

I have a json file which I read in. I want to first filter the json data to return the object defined by the datasetID, then get out the datasetName. I have filtered in javascript, but would prefer to stay in php but I can't figure it out, any ideas?

note: `foreach` is not required as only a single record is returned when filtered using the datasetID. So rather than using a `foreach` method how would you swelect a single record, `first` for instance?

```
$datasetID = '5fd4058e5c8d2'; // unique 13 character string

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents(path/to/file), True);
```

So I need to first filter for the unique object with $datasetID = '5fd4058e5c8d2';

```
$filtered_data =
```

Then I need to return the attribute datasetName from that object

```
$datasetName =
```

pointers to the best ways to do this is welcomed.

Sample json data:

```
[
   [
      {
         "datasetID":"5fd4124900827",
         "institutionCode":"None",
         "collectionCode":"None",
         "datasetName":"None"
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "datasetID":"5fd4058e5c8d2",
         "institutionCode":"None",
         "collectionCode":"None",
         "datasetName":"None",
      }
   ]
]
```

Comment: Why does your data have nested arrays with only one element each?

Comment: Is array_filter needed here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php filtering json file and returning attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65314494/php-filtering-json-file-and-returning-attribute-value)

Comment: @Phil that was generated by a recusive search and merging of individual json files. I assume not the best way to do it.

Comment: @Daedalus yes this question was closed before, I have added the requested information and I have looked into it, please don't vote for this to be closed again, it's far better to be constructive. I can only find `foreach` filtering rather than just returning a single record which is the behaviour detailed here.

Comment: @SpatialDigger Edit the original question if you want it reopened, but don't post a duplicate of it.  You've been here for 4 years.  This isn't the way things are done.

Comment: @Daedalus I have edited it but I don't know how to reopen a closed question, it says `You can edit the question or post a new one.` so I made a new post with more information.

Comment: @SpatialDigger That message is unfortunately flawed, and there are [requests to have this changed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400273/how-do-i-ask-a-good-question-page-needs-explicit-statement-dont-repost-your) because of this confusion.  To reopen the question, edit it with the required information and it will be entered into the reopen queue automatically, so make sure the edit edits in all required information.  Lastly, see [Barmar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65314494/php-filtering-json-file-and-returning-attribute-value#comment115469778_65314494).

Comment: @SpatialDigger Some of your elements doesn't have datasetID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how you got that JSON but it is nested deeper than needed.  You can merge the top level arrays to flatten it, then index on `datasetID`:

```
$data = array_merge(...$data);
$filtered_data = array_column($data, null, 'datasetID')[$datasetID];
$datasetName = $filtered_data['datasetName'];
```

Shorter:

```
$filtered_data = array_column(array_merge(...$data), null, 'datasetID')[$datasetID];
$datasetName = $filtered_data['datasetName'];
```

Or to keep them all to use:

```
$data = array_column(array_merge(...$data), null, 'datasetID');
$datasetName = $data[$datasetID]['datasetName'];
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried with your sample JSON.

First, `json_decode` will return a `PHP` array to use `foreach` on it. I wrote a simple `foreach` and checked your searching ID is equal to element's datasetID. If it is equal this is the datasetName you are searching for.

```
<?php

$json = '[[{"datasetID":"5fd4124900827","institutionCode":"None","collectionCode":"None","datasetName":"None"}],[{"datasetID":"5fd4058e5c8d2","institutionCode":"None","collectionCode":"None","datasetName":"None"}]]';
 
$elements    = json_decode($json,TRUE);
$searchingID = "5fd4058e5c8d2";

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    if(isset($element[0]['datasetID']) && $element[0]['datasetID'] == $searchingID){
        $filtered_data = $element[0];
        break;
    }
}

echo $filtered_data['datasetName']; // or return $filtered_data['datasetName'];

?>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but I would iterate `$element` instead of assuming it's only ever got one element. You can also short-circuit this by exiting the iterations as soon as you find a match

Comment: Thank you @oguzhancerit I went with the other answer because it avoided the needless foreach since datasetID will always be a unique id.

Comment: @SpatialDigger np, you are right and that was good.